# Tailwind css, how to set default font color?

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind css in my project, due to our application styles we are using a default font color, however I cannot seem to find how to do this in tailwind, the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color) page only talks about extending the color palette, but not how to set a default color.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: See: [Adding Base Styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-base-styles) in the docs.

Comment: oh wow, this is not a configurable property on the tailwind.config.js file?

Comment: You can also specify [theme](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme) defaults in the configuration file, and access those in your CSS using [`theme()`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I ended up solving this in the dumbest way possible, on a global css file:

```css
html {
  @apply text-gray-800
}
```

Not pretty but at least I can use the tailwind classes

Comment: In the base layer?

Comment: I didn't bother to understand what the tailwind layers do, you are possibly right, I just wanted to get it working

Comment: [@layer](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#layer). Doesn't really matter here, since it's not a class, but you can't go wrong by wrapping in it a base layer.

Answer (score 23):

There is few options, you can add class to the `<body>` or `<html>` tag:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body class="text-green-500">
  </body>
</html>
```

or you can just extend base layer in your `index.css` file:

```css
@tailwind base;

@layer base {
  html {
    @apply text-green-500;
  } 
}

@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Let's check a [Tailwind play example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/54UrOn1txd)

Comment: Part two is my preferred solution

Comment: I like to create a custom color in my theme (tailwind.config.js), and use that in `@apply text-fg`

Answer (score 5):

I ended up here while trying to do this in my `tailwind.config.js` file.

Here's how for anyone who needs it:

```js
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    plugin(({addBase, theme}) => {
      addBase({
        // or whichever color you'd like
        'html': {color: theme('colors.slate.800')},
      });
    })
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you just add the attribute to the body tag?

```
<body class="text-gray-800"></body>
```