# Set default color for text in Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

What is the correct way to assign default values to all text on the website using Tailwind CSS?

Is there a setting in `tailwind.config.js` for that?

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow ? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not a solution for me.

Comment: Please extrapolate and explain what you're not happy with so, because I cannot help you solve an issue if you do not use the right tool nor provide feedback.

Comment: I am having the same issue. The problem with that answer is (for me at least), it overwrites other colors I set. Lets say I set a color of an inline swg image to green (it is done by text-green-500), your answer then overwrites it to blue. What we need is the other way - set a default, which can be overwritten. Not something, that overwrites everything

Comment: For this, you need to understand how CSS cascade works. You can this article to understand it a bit better: https://wattenberger.com/blog/css-cascade#position Essentially, if you want to have it as a default and override it afterwards, just define `text-blue-500` at the top of all of your CSS, then re-define it afterwards by applying CSS on top of it. It will keep it as blue by default and you can override it by red below the cascade. Requires some organization, indeed. But it's not Tailwind's job to handle this, it's your CSS organization that handles this one.

Comment: And how could I do that with tailwind-css. That is the anwer we are looking for.

Comment: It's **not** TailwindCSS job to do this. You **can** do it with it, but you may just write a basic CSS style line at the **top** of your styles. Then override it afterwards with Tailwind. Again, basic CSS cascade here, get some read about the subject to understand how it works IMO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind css, how to set default font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65322933/tailwind-css-how-to-set-default-font-color)

Comment: @MartinSchaer pretty much like my answer basically.

Comment: @kissu is correct; it's not Tailwind's job to APPLY the classes in your HTML. Its job is to PROVIDE the classes. If you want to apply the same class on everything on all your pages, add the code to the CSS as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly do that in tailwind, meanwhile you can set the text to use a specific color globally with something like

```
* {
  @apply text-blue-500; // can also customize it to have a `text-primary-500`
}
```

And customize the blue color values to your liking: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#curating-colors